# Unable to apply new Android Layout

Tags: android, layout, styles, themes

I'm developing an Android app compatible from devices with Android 2.3.6 up to 4.3. I'd like it to look modern in the layout but I'm unable to get it. For example, this is a screenshot of the [DataPicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzoQv.png) Android gives me. I use support.v4.app.jar to make it compatible. Is that the problem? Should I compile my app for different platforms differently? Should I change the minSDK version in the Manifest?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please specify how you want to display your layout exactly. Do you need to change the whole layout or you just have problem with the default style date picker?

Comment: I have problems with DataPicker, Buttons, SeekBar etc. Everything has an old layout

Comment: Actually it is not a problem because all controls will look natively for platform that is understandable and habitually for user. If you want custom style - read my answer to your post.

Comment: What I don't understand is why I have the same layout on a 2.3.6 phone AND a 4.3 phone. For example in 2.3.6 the seekbar is big and awful why in 4.3 is much better. BUT why the seekbar automatically doesn't beome "nice" on newer platforms?

Comment: Because you applied old style (theme) on your seekbar. Please provide screen-shots if it is possible.

Comment: The DataPicker is a screenshot of what I see on Android 4.3, which is not the standard expected

Answer (score 2):

If you want Holo style for your controlls - you can use [holoeverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) lib. Or add just custom styles for controlls for all platforms. Here is backport of [DatePicker](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-datepicker)